# how to put your loop from a guitar looper into logic?

Tags: tempo, logic-pro, looping

hey guys okay my question sounds weird, I explain:
I have a looper RC-20xl boss. I recorded a lot of loops that I found really nice, I would like to record them on my logic and be able to use them. So I suppose I will need to set a very precise tempo on them. Anyone got any idea of how I can do that?
I just tried to record them on logic and play with the miliseconds in order to get a correct bpm but I reckon that's so long to do it must be an other way!! 
ALSO my looper doesn't have any MIDI output 
cheers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. You don't want to just hit record in Logic and then play the loop(s) in? You want it somehow synced to a click track and/or grid in Logic? How much do you know about the Boss's clock? If it has MIDI input, can it be set to synchronize to MIDI clock in?

Comment: hey so I kind of found out, I did hit record in Logic and then played the loop in, I cut to have the right timing and then Logic allows you to find the exact bpm of the selected region.

Comment: but now my problem is that my looper is actually noisy, BOSS pedals are super noisy anyway. So when I record it in Logic I have this huge background noise that I don't have if I play it through the amp

Comment: Don't use the guitar pedal at all -- any processing can be done in Logic. Just send the guitar's output as directly into the computer as you can without anything in between.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking for an audio-export feature, something that shows up only in more recent devices, like the [RC-30](https://www.boss.info/us/products/rc-30/). That has a USB port, which you can use to transfer WAV files both to and from the pedal.

Your solution of recording the pedal's output with Logic can probably be made to work. You may be able to cut down on the noise in a few ways:

- Try running the pedal on battery power, with nothing physically connected except your computer. This removes the possibility of a [ground loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_(electricity)), a common noise source.
- Try turning the output volume (LEVEL) up. If the noise is being added to the signal *after* the circuitry that controls the volume, the loop's volume will increase, but not the noise.
- Try turning the input volume (MIC/INST) up. This will only work for new loops. This works basically the same way as the previous point, and will help if the noise is added *before* the circuitry that controls the output volume.